# Python: Converting decimals into months

Tags: python, date, decimal

The function below returns: Your monthly payment would be $529.22 for 6.25 years, and a downpayment of $4620.06.

How could I convert the decimal to 4 months instead of .25 years.

I would like the output to read: Your monthly payment would be $529.22 for 6 years and 4 months, and a downpayment of $4620.06.

```
def newcar():

input("How much is a new car going to cost you per month? Please hit 
enter to start")
p = int(input("Please enter total cost of car: "))
r = float(input("Please enter interest rate as a whole number(example: 
15.6% = 15.6): National average is around 10.5%):  "))
t = int(input("These payments would last for how many months?: "))
dp = int(input("Please enter the downpayment percentage as a whole 
number: example: 20% = 20: "))
afterdp = p - (p * dp/100)
downpay = p - afterdp
downpay = round(downpay, 2)
interest = afterdp * (r/100) * (t/12)
interest = round(interest, 2) 
monthly_payment_bt = (afterdp + interest)/t
monthly_payment_bt = round(monthly_payment_bt, 2)
monthly_payment = (monthly_payment_bt * .07) + monthly_payment_bt
monthly_payment = round(monthly_payment, 2)
t = round(t/12, 2)
return("Your monthly payment would be $" + str(monthly_payment)  +  " 
for " + str(t) + " years, and a downpayment of $" +  str(downpay))

print(newcar())
```

Comment: Just do `.25 * 12` and `round()` it... Btw, 25% of 1 year is equal to 3 months, not 4.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not calculating the interest correctly. Normally the interest is compounded monthly, so you don't pay interest on the part that's already paid off (but you do pay interest on the previous interest). I'd suggest using [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator#Monthly_payment_formula) and doing your calculation with an integer number of months (rather than a fractional number of years).

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the years to an integer and convert the decimal part * 12 to a month :

```
def singular_or_plural(count, word):
    if count == 1:
        return "1 %s" % word
    elif count > 1:
        return "%d %ss" % (count, word)


def years_and_months(float_year):
    year = int(float_year)
    month = int((float_year % 1) * 12)
    words = [(year, 'year'), (month, 'month')]
    return ' and '.join(singular_or_plural(count, word)
                        for (count, word) in words if count > 0)

print(years_and_months(0.09))
print(years_and_months(0.50))
print(years_and_months(1))
print(years_and_months(2))
print(years_and_months(2.5))
print(years_and_months(2.99))
print(years_and_months(6.25))
```

It outputs:

```
1 month
6 months
1 year
2 years
2 years and 6 months
2 years and 11 months
6 years and 3 months
```

Before calling this fonction, you could check that the duration is at least a month.